# php curl performing an sftp connection with my servers ip address

Tags: php, ftp

Am trying to perform an ftp connection to another server.

So currently i have done

```
$host="server_to_connet_ip"

ftp_connect ( $host [ 21 [, int $timeout = 90 ]] )
```

This works totally fine when the the server to connect to doesnt limit the ip address.

Currently there is a limit on the ip address that can connect to the server and my vps ip address has already been whitelisted
How can i still perform the ftp connection with the origin ip address as my server ip address(where application is hosted) as currently each and every request i make happen to appear to be from my local computer outgoing ip address not the servers(where application is hosted) ip address

I have also checked on using curl as an alternative but i cannot figure out how.

SO in curl this would be something like

```
curl ftp://serverip --user myname:mypassword
```

But how can this be achieved in such away that when performing the ftp connection request the request will originate from my server ip address(when i host my application) not my local computer ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's not possible to spoof an IP and receive a response because the response will go to the IP that you spoofed and you aren't actually calling from there.

You need to add the IP that you will be connecting from to the whitelist on the server you are connecting to.

Comment: Regulary the connection will happen via a cron job so basically i expect the ip address the request will be originating from will be the servers ip address when the cron job runs

Comment: add that server ip to the whitelist on the server it is connecting to

Comment: The server ip address is already whitelisted as pointed out on the question. What am worried about is during the testing phase as i have to  test with my local computer is there a way to initiate the request from a local computer pass it through my server them make the request from the server with the origin been my server when ill host the application. Eg: i have a server 1.2.3.4 the server am to connect to is 9.0.0.0 when i make the request to the server 1.2.3.4 i want this to be passed to 9.0.0.0 and the origin should be 1.2.3.4